Keep a Mac working on a terminal task
I would like to keep a process going on a Mac.  I'm starting the process in a terminal (doesn't matter using TMUX or not), locking the screen and walking away.  Several hours later I see the process didn't get run and has died about 10 min after Lock Screen started.
I have turned off energy saving features during the Lock Screen (and monitor but I would like to turn that back on).
There is no administrator changing settings on me, it's just a home computer.
Anything else I should check?

There is a terminal app that you can install via homebrew and then run in a terminal to prevent your Mac from going to sleep.
brew install --cask caffeine

After installing have a look in the man pages to familiarize with the parameters.
man caffeinate

E.g. if you run it without parameter -t you can give a timeout in seconds when it stops or with -i it will observe another process and stops when this process is no longer active.
